# How to install emacs colortheme

Tags: emacs

I found [this website](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) and downloaded the color-theme files.
It says:

> Put the file color-theme.el and the
>   folder “themes” (with the files
>   color-theme-example.el and
>   color-theme-library.el) in a directory
>   on your LoadPath.

and then I checked [the load path website](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath), which says:

> To add a single directory to the load-path:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")
```

My question is, where do I type this line?
If I do `M-x` and then type, it complains `add-to-list[No match]`.

By the way, I am using Emacs 23.2(9.0) on Mac, a GUI version.
For the text version on terminal, I use black background seems fine, except the blue is too dark on black

Answer (score 37):

**An answer for newbs like me!**

In Emacs 24.5.1, on mac or linux the following will work.

The following command will create a folder called themes inside your  .emacs.d folder (assuming one does not already exist)

```
mkdir ~/.emacs.d/themes/
```

Now tell emacs that you have installed a themes folder. In emacs open your .emacs file, by typing the following:

```
C-x C-f ;;;this opens a new .emacs file or creates one if it doesn't exist
```

Add the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
```

Now copy your theme's '.el' file to your .emacs.d/themes/ directory. A good place to find custom themes is here: [emacsthemes.com](https://emacsthemes.com)

Now load your custom theme by typing the following:

```
M-x customize-themes ;;;now press return
```

Your newly installed themes should appear on the list like so:

[image: emacs *Custom Themes* buffer]

Move your cursor to within the '[  ]' and press return to select that theme.

*Enjoy emacs!*

Comment: `M-x  customize-themes` working for me, not `M-x  customise-themes`.

Comment: Yeah, Emacs understands British English :)

Answer (score 13):

You can download Emacs 24 for Mac from [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/) and **Emacs 24 already has a built-in theming system**. You can call it by `M-x customize-themes` and choose whatever themes you like. And you can find much more themes online. There is actually a quite nice theme called "solarized", you can use it both in GUI and command line.

Answer (score 9):

I load color theme by this code:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/themes/zenburn.el")
(zenburn)
```

Comment: I assume this goes to the .emacs file, right? Is there a way to check where the init file my emacs is actually looking for. Because I am using the Mac OS GUI version, I suspect it doesn't check .emacs at ~

Answer (score 2):

In emacs 23, I thought color theme is installed by default. If not, and you need to add that line, write it in either file `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, `~/.emacs.el` or `~/.emacs`

Comment: thanks! so .emacs or .emacs.el doesn't exist in my ~, I am just wondering where is the default "loadpath".

Comment: Strange. If you are using linux, you should have it. But even if you don't, you can just create a file named like that, and it will work by default.

Comment: I am using Mac OS. I created it and added the line. It seems it still cannot load the color theme mode. I am feeling this troublesome. If there is a version with default color theme installed, I am happy using that.

Comment: What happens if you put `.emacs.el` within `.emacs.d`? Maybe you should further change the file name so that you have `.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: I found a version has default installation

Comment: http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html this works; My old one is from http://emacsformacosx.com/, this has no colortheme

Comment: @Alfred I have an idea. Try changing some settings like fontface using the dropdown menu and save it. Then, it shall show in the small buffer at the bottom of your window that it saved the settings to a certain file. That will be your configurarion file. After that, you can delete the setting that was added automatically.

Comment: notice the carbon emacs is emac 22 and the other "gnu" one is 22, but I guess I don't care the version

Comment: @Alfred Oh. Good that you found it.

Comment: From the EmacsWiki: "if ~/.emacs does not exist, Emacs will try ~/.emacs.d/init.el"

Answer (score 2):

You should put that line in your [init file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile#init_file). This is usually the file `~/.emacs`. The [.emacs.d](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD) directory is a conventional directory for storing your personal customization files. Many of the instructions for installing packages (like color theme) or explaining other parts of Emacs (like the load-path page) assume you understand the init file.

`.emacs` and `.emacs.d` are really at the core of Emacs customization. If you read up on those, Emacs will make a lot more sense. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, John, would you please point me to a sample .emacs file?

Comment: I get it working now. Here is my .emacs                               ;; Color theme                                                                  
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0")                         
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0/themes")                  
(require 'color-theme)                                                          
(color-theme-initialize)                                                        
(setq color-theme-is-global t)                                                  
(color-theme-arjen)